# Admin on rest add new resource to store dynamically

Tags: react-redux, admin-on-rest

My project is structured like [this](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html).

As you can see there are three resources(posts, users, comments) defined. 
So you cannot perform CRUD operations on any other resource. I am not using any custom clients (using aor-loopback rest client)

I would like to dynamically add new resources to the store so that I can access those tables/models/resources for CRUD. I know its possible (but don't know how), because we can update the store on the fly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution my problem. Sharing it for anyone who encounters the same.

import { DECLARE_RESOURCES } from 'admin-on-rest';

and use this action to re-initialise all the resources with an additional one.

Cheers.